# Finding area of triangles inside an isososeles triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area, angle

**Hello,**
I was going through some Olympiad math questions, when I came across this question

> In $\triangle ABC, AB = AC, \angle A = 120°.$ Points $D, E, F$ are on segments $BC, CA, AB$ respectively such that $CD = CE, BD = BF, DE = 10, FD = 6$. Find area of $\triangle DEF$.

This question left me in a haze, for the fact that the diagram can't be drawn using *scale-compass* and it even can't be drawn on geogebra (The point E comes outside $\overline{AC}$, while the question states that it is on the line)
 Using **Extension of Pythagoras Theorem** ($a^2 = b^2 + c^2 + bc \sqrt 3$) where the values of the number rooted is correspondent to the angles or cosine rule, I get irrational numbers as the lengths and am not able to proceed further. I intended using *Herons formula* due to the lack of side lengths but am not able to find the length of $\overline{FE}$.
Can I get some hints to solve it using plain geometry(I know it has some thing to do with excentres but I'm not able to make any observations on this point)
**ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's $$\frac{6\cdot10\sin30^{\circ}}{2}=15.$$

The geometric solution.

Let $FK$ be an altitude of $\Delta FDE$.

Thus, since $$\measuredangle FDE=180^{\circ}-2\cdot75^{\circ}=30^{\circ},$$
we obtain:
$$FK=\frac{1}{2}FD=3$$ and
$$S_{\Delta DEF}=\frac{3\cdot10}{2}=15.$$

Comment: What formula did you use, and can you please tell me the geometric method of solving it if present

Comment: @Adithya Dsilva I added something. See now.

Answer (score 1):

Your discovery that the problem is inconsistent is correct.  $BFD$ and $CDE$ are $30-75-75$ triangles, which gives $BD=\frac 3{\sin 15^\circ}\approx 11.59, CD=\frac 5{\sin 15^\circ}\approx 19.31$ and $E$ lies beyond $A$ from $C$.  Report that fact and you are done.

If you let $E$ be on the extension of $CA$ and want to find the area of $DEF$ anyway, note that $\angle FDE=30^\circ$, use the law of cosines to get the length of $FE$ and you have all three sides for Heron's formula.

Comment: How to find the area of it if it is outside the line? Can you please give me a hint or something in the current post? Thank You